# Deploy a Cordova App from Visual Studio to Device

Tags: javascript, ios, visual-studio, cordova, phonegap

I want to deploy a Cordova App created in Visual Studio to my iPhone. I have a MacBook that runs Remotebuild and i added the Host to Visual Studio. The connection is fine - when I try to build the terminal on my MacBook starts working.

The only Problem is something with "Provisioning Profiles" but i can't solve this problem.

What I've already tryed:

- Created a App with xCode (Blank App) with the BundeIdentifier "test.mycompany" and renamed the Cordovas BundleIdentifier also to "test.mycompany"

  - Created Provisioning Profile in the Apple Developer Dashboard, download it and added this Profile to my Device with XCode->Devices

What can I try next? I'm trying this for weeks...

> Check dependencies Signing for "test" requires a development team.
>   Select a development team in the project editor. Code signing is
>   required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  Check dependencies (1 failure)
>   Fehler beim Erstellen der App für die "BuildNumber" 5524: Error code
>   65 for command: xcodebuild with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Users/grafikschulung/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/5524/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,test.xcodeproj,-target,test,-configuration,Debug,-destination,platform=iOS,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/grafikschulung/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/5524/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/grafikschulung/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/5524/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Comment: Can you add more details about the error?

Comment: @connor I added everything I have

Comment: Help me please guys